# Equally distributed data based on partitioning in Pub sub lite

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-pubsublite

i am new to GCP
Have created 2 partition in Lite Topics . I am trying to publish  8 files which should equally distributed on those 2 partition.
Is it possible to make this in Python?
So far have refer to this documentation
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/publishing

Comment: A topic consists of a set of partitions which can be scaled up to increase the capacity of the topic.  As per this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/topics#:~:text=Storage%20configuration%3A) you can set storage i.e. maximum total size of the messages per partition. Could you describe your initial requirement/use case for distributing equal messages in partitions?